deck.gl GeoJSON point layer not extruding
I have a GeoJSON layer in deck.gl which I'm trying to extrude based on the elevation property.
E.g.
 {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -5.922324439117051,
                    54.60048441062634
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "elevation": 3.7030000000000003,
                "color": [
                    183,
                    180,
                    174,
                    255
                ]
            }
        },

so far I've tried this
  const layers = [
    new GeoJsonLayer<BlockProperties>({
      id: 'geojson',
      data,
      opacity: 0.8,
      stroked: false,
      filled: true,
      wireframe: true,
      extruded: true,
      getFillColor: f => new Uint8ClampedArray(f.properties.color),
      getElevation: f => f.properties.elevation,
      pointRadiusScale: 0.15, 
      getLineColor: [255, 255, 255],
      pickable: true
    })
  ];

but even with extruded set as true and getElevation, the points remain flat?
